# Convert functional component from class component

Tags: reactjs

I want to convert my class component to functional component and t is difficult for me to convert render() of class component.
Here is my code sandbox link. https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-smoke-s65vx4?file=/src/App.js
Can anyone please help me with this

Comment: Please add chatDataForTest.json file in your code.

Comment: I have added it. please check

Answer (score 0):

The render part is just going to be the body of the function and the return.

```
const myfunccomp : React.FC = ({id, info, msgList}) => {
    const chatContentHeader = () => {...}
    const chatContentBody = () => {...}
    const chatContentFooter = () => {...}
    ...
    return (
      <div className="chat-content">
        {chatContentHeader(info.name)}
        {chatContentBody(msgList, id)}
        {chatContentFooter()}
      </div>
    );
  }
```